# Linux system() after setting SA_NOCLDWAIT to SIGCHLD

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

The man page of `system()` [states](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) that "During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked"
In my code I'm installing a handler for `SIGCHLD` that writes something to the log and ignores the signal. I do this to know about children that exited in my log and avoid zombie processes.

A problem occurs when I use the `system()` call. With this handler in place `system()` always returns `-1` and not the child's exit code. But according to the above quote from the man page, `system()` is supposed to handle the signals from the child.

What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
static void handleSignal(int signum, siginfo_t* inf, void* ctx) {
    cout << "in signal " << signum << endl;
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction chldsa, prevchld;
    chldsa.sa_sigaction = &handleSignal;
    sigemptyset(&chldsa.sa_mask);
    chldsa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_NOCLDWAIT;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &chldsa, &prevchld) == -1) {
        cout << "Failed setting sigaction SIGCHLD " << errno;
    }

    int x = system("exit 1");
    cout << "RET=" << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: First, that's C++, not C. They are different languages, even if they have similarities. Second, `system(string)` in Linux is equivalent to executing `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", string, NULL);` in a child process (as required by POSIX.1 compatibility). Why not write it yourself? As long as SIGCHLD is not ignored (`SIG_IGN`), it's a very simple function to implement. Need an example? While it does solve your problem, it is not exactly an answer to your question -- unless you consider *"don't use system(), use your own version instead"* a valid answer.

Comment: not using `system()` is not an option. It's not my code that does it.

Comment: Also, `execl()` AFAIK is not equivalent to `system()` since it doesn't do `fork()`

Comment: You did write *"when I use `system()`"*. Also, which part of "`execl()` in a child process" did you fail to understand?

Comment: The part that I missed while reading :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550217/linux-system-sigchld-handling-multithreading

Answer (score 3):

If you *only* want to get rid of the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` and its effects, simply reap all children at the *end* of your `SIGCHLD` handler instead.

Edited to add: Just verified that the following:

```
    pid_t p;

    /* Reap all pending child processes */
    do {
        p = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
    } while (p != (pid_t)0 && p != (pid_t)-1);
```

works fine when run last in a `SIGCHLD` handler (installed `SA_NOCLDSTOP  |SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO`). No zombies, and `system()` returns the correct exit status.

Note that [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) is an [async-signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) function in Linux, per POSIX.1-2004, and the `WNOHANG` means the call will never block, so the above loop is safe.

However, since standard signals are not queued, it is possible that if two or more processes exit with just the right timing, with one exiting just after the child-reaping loop is executed in your parent process but before the signal handler returns, one or more children are not immediately reaped. They will, when the next child process exits, though. To mitigate this, you should run the above loop periodically, either as part of your program's normal operation, or say via a timer interrupt. The loop never blocks, and consumes very little CPU time.

Remember, `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)` will return zero if there are alive children, `-1` with `errno == ECHILD` if there are no alive children, or the process ID of a process that was just reaped. (If you wanted to, you could utilize the loop in your logging, using a non-NULL status pointer to capture the exit status of each child that has exited, and logging it. You could even hook a periodic timer to the same signal handler, for example.)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it worked for a single threaded application. In a multithreaded application this is still broken since the signal is received by a different thread where it is not blocked.

Comment: In a multithreaded application, with rare exceptions which do not apply to `SIGCHLD`, you want to block all async signals in all threads except the one that's meant to field them. The reliable way to do that is to wrap all calls to `pthread_create` in appropriate calls to `pthread_sigmask`, so the child inherits the right mask. (If you try to call `pthread_sigmask` on the child side of `pthread_create`, there is a race window where inappropriate signals can be delivered to the child.)

Comment: @Zack: I don't typically block async signals for my thread. First, I know about `EINTR` and deal with it whenever appropriate; second, I often use (realtime) signals delivered to a specific thread to interrupt a blocking syscall for e.g. timeouts. I dare say you are making an overreaching assertion here. Relying on `SIGCHLD` delivered to a specific thread -- remembering that it is not queued -- instead of reaping all children whenever *a* `SIGCHLD` is received, is asking for trouble. You just *do not get* a `SIGCHLD` for every child that exits, even if using a dedicated reaper thread.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I think you misunderstand - the advice to make sure all async signals are blocked in all threads that don't expect them is in response to shoosh's complaint about the signal being fielded by the wrong thread, in their multithreaded application.  It's orthogonal to your point about looping through `waitpid`.  I admit I don't see what `EINTR` has to do with this, or why you wouldn't use `SA_RESTART` and forget about it.

Comment: @Zack: Oh! I interpreted your comment in a too wide context. As to `EINTR`: Signal delivery causes a currently blocking non-async-signal safe function to return -1 with `errno==EINTR`. I take advantage of that very often: timeouts, async event notification via `pthread_sigqueue()` on a realtime signal, etc. It does mean I/O functions need a retry loop. While `SA_RESTART` flag stops this from happening for most (but not all) functions, I don't usually rely on it. I *benefit* from and *use* the signal delivery events, so blocking them by default wastes an useful tool for no gain, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Errno should show that SA_NOCLDWAIT is the issue. By providing this flag you are indicating that you are not interested in the status of children.  This included children created and managed by system().  Internally system is calling waitpid will follow:

> POSIX.1-2001 specifies that if the disposition of SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN or the SA_NOCLDWAIT flag is set for SIGCHLD (see sigaction(2)), then children that terminate do not become zombies and a call to wait() or waitpid() will block until all children have terminated, and then fail with errno set to ECHILD.

Clearly you are intested in the status of children. You are checking the status returned from system(). So either remove the flag or manage all children without waiting.

If you are in the situation where you have to use system() and have code that expects children to be automatically reaped you could use your handler.  This would not collect the system() child as the signal is blocked from delivery for the duration of the call. Something like:

```
while (waitpid((pid_t)(-1), 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {}
```

Comment: Correct, andygavin. However, since in Linux the `SIGCHLD` signal *is* generated, one can utilize that instead of `wait()` or `waitpid()`. For example, one can use `sigwaitinfo()` to wait for the desired `SIGCHLD` signal, calling the handler directly for all other `SIGCHLD`s that might be caught. That's why I asked @shoosh if they needed an example. The implementation is quite straightforward, but Linux-specific (due to the `SIGCHLD` signal behaviour required; I haven't checked whether *BSD's or other systems provide similar behaviour).

Comment: The headline of the question clearly states that it is SA_NOCLDWAIT the causes the problem. My question is - how do I get around it and make it work.

Comment: The flag is incompatible with system(). I was trying to indicate that you should drop the flag if you want to use system().  You can't elect to manage some children's statuses and allow the system to reap the rest.